# Alexa with lambda function parsing json error

Tags: json, node.js, lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Developing Alexa with lambda function, json parsing error

How to parse json response

```
{
"Status": true,
"Error": "",
"Data": [
    {
        "Traffic": 6231
    }
],
"Message": null
}
```

My code

```
result.Data[0].Traffic
```

error :

```
    START RequestId: 4578b114-9bba-11e8-94a6-611a9b05be3f Version: $LATEST
2018-08-09T09:54:57.434Z    4578b114-9bba-11e8-94a6-611a9b05be3f    Warning: Application ID is not set
2018-08-09T09:54:57.435Z    4578b114-9bba-11e8-94a6-611a9b05be3f    traffic Plaza: sutpl1
2018-08-09T09:54:58.028Z    4578b114-9bba-11e8-94a6-611a9b05be3f    TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at IncomingMessage.res.on (/var/task/index.js:487:32)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
END RequestId: 4578b114-9bba-11e8-94a6-611a9b05be3f
REPORT RequestId: 4578b114-9bba-11e8-94a6-611a9b05be3f  Duration: 654.57 ms Billed Duration: 700 ms     Memory Size: 576 MB Max Memory Used: 34 MB  
RequestId: 4578b114-9bba-11e8-94a6-611a9b05be3f Process exited before completing request
```

Comment: Try with something like this, because if you look at the error you have a type error:


    if(result.Data.length > 0 && result.Data[0].Traffic) {
     result.Data[0].Traffic;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found myself getting this error as well. Instead of appending with a period, try the following: `result['Data']` to access the list and `result['Data']['Traffic']` to get the value 6231.

Comment: Thank you. I found result['data'] null.